# Other common protocols besides HTTP?

Tags: http, protocols

I usually pass data between my web servers (in different locations) using HTTP requests (sometimes using SSL if it's sensitive). I was wondering if there were any **lighter protocols** that I might be able to swap HTTP(S) for that would also support public/private keys like SSH or something.

I used PHP sockets to build a SMTP client before so I wouldn't mind doing that if required.

Comment: HTTP is pretty lightweight already...

Comment: Oh? Hmmm.. I just assumed that since it was so widely used it must be bloated like SOAP, Wordpress, Windows, and other things...

Comment: Well quite :)  HTTP is also ubiquitous and used in countless different problem domains. That's testament to its flexibility and lack of baggage. The same cannot be said for those others.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There are lots and lots and lots of protocols.  Lots.  Start here for a list.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Protocol_Suite

SFTP is fun for passing data around.  It works well.  You'll find that it's not much better than HTTP, however, because HTTP is pretty simple.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol

SMTP would work.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Mail_Transfer_Protocol

SNMP can be made to work.  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_Network_Management_Protocol  You have to really push the envelope.

All of these, however, involve TCP/IP sockets, which involve a fair amount of overhead because of the negotiation for a connection and the acknowledgement of packets.

If you want real fun with very low overhead, use UDP.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol

You might want to use Reliable UDP if you're worried about messages getting dropped.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reliable_User_Datagram_Protocol

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into UDP and RDUP. But perhaps it's best to just remain with HTTP. I'll need to figure out some kind of benchmark.

Comment: Would [wrk](https://github.com/wg/wrk?ref=thechiefio) work for your benchmarking need?

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to mention [XMPP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensible_Messaging_and_Presence_Protocol) in addition to protocols already listed in other answers.

It's lightweight, and it is used in some "realtime" communication systems (for example, in GTalk).

Comment: XML isn't a light as JSON, so there are wasted packets with XMPP. Then again, the protocol could be changed to use JSON or some other simple, high-compression transfer.

Answer (score 2):

[WebSocket](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) is a good option if you are interested in keeping a connection open to pass multiple messages back and forth. It's useful for issuing updates from the server to clients in real time, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply use FTPS:

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS

or SFTP

> http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_file_transfer_protocol

Comment: Well, I don't want to just put the data on the other server - I want the data to be received and handled by it. I guess I could setup cron jobs to look for new uploaded files - but that would lag behind realtime.

Comment: Fun thing is, in the protocol you are just sending data with some arbitrary file name. You could easily have a client that sends a fake file with generated data, and a server that takes the data and processes it without actually storing the file. In fact, that's not much different from a `.htm` "file" that would appear in a url, which is in fact generated by a server side script.

Answer (score 0):

gRPC (Google Remote Procedure Call) is also an option
https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/ especially if you aim for speed

Check the intro https://grpc.io/docs/what-is-grpc/introduction/

and a comparison to http/rest https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/grpc/comparison?view=aspnetcore-8.0